# ¿Como restar en Report Viewer registros de un mismo campo?

Tags: c#, sql, reportviewer

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
El siguiente reporte, trae la siguiente consulta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el reporte, como puedo restar el monto?
Cuando intento poner un TextBox y poniendolo de esta manera da error:
**=(Fields!MONTO.Value - Fields!MONTO.Value, "dsEstadisticos")**

Comment: Que error te da?

Comment: Error  The Value expression for the textrun ‘Textbox35.Paragraphs[0].TextRuns[0]’ contains an error: [BC30198] ')' expected.

Comment: @Pikoh chequea arriba

Comment: El error te dice que te falta un parentesis. de todas maneras...el textbox donde lo estas poniendo?  es una columna dentro de la tabla del reporte?

Comment: @Pikoh No, pero ahora lo puse, Esto es lo que estoy escribiendo y dice que falta parentesis =(Fields!MONTO.Value - Fields!MONTO.Value, "dsEstadisticos") pero cuando le pongo el SUM delante se quita: =sum(Fields!MONTO.Value - Fields!MONTO.Value, "dsEstadisticos")

Comment: Claro, por eso te preguntaba. Si lo que quieres es poner la suma en todos los registros en una caja de texto, debes usar la función sum. Si se trata de una columna de la tabla, debes poner `=Fields!MONTO.Value - Fields!MONTO.Value`, porque suma en cada fila

Comment: Eso es lo que pasa que se muestra en 0 es como si la resta no funcionara =Fields!MONTO.Value - Fields!MONTO.Value

Comment: @Pikoh no se resta

Comment: Y si haces `=CInt(Fields!MONTO.Value) - CInt(Fields!MONTO.Value)` ?